# res.end inside a nested series of callback

Tags: node.js, express

Ok I have the following codes

```
   router.route('/getParkData/:parkLocationId').get(function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.parkLocationId;
  var parkdata = {};
  parkInfo(id).then(function(data){
  if(data.parking_type == 'FREE')
  {


    var json = JSON.stringify({
      "error" : null,
      "result" : null,
      "message" : "free",
      "error_code" : null
    });
       res.end(json);
  }
  else
    return getTwowheelers(id)
   }).then(function(data){
    if(data[0].parking_type)
       {
         parkdata.parkingType = data[0].parking_type;
      }
      else
      {
         parkdata.parkingType = "paid";
      }

    if(data.length > 0)
      {
       parkdata.tw = data[0].rate.tw[0];
      }
      else
       {
          parkdata.tw= 0;
       }
      return getFourwheelers(id);
     }).then(function(data){
     console.log(data.length);
       if(data.length > 0)
                {
                  parkdata.fw = data[0].rate.fw[0];
                }
                else
                {
                             parkdata.fw = 0;
                }
          res.json(mResponse.response(null, parkdata, "Success",200));
     }).catch(function(err){
       res.json(mResponse.response(null, null, "No data!",500));
     });

});
```

So I was doing a quick fix by checking the condition and ending the respons.Its working fine but I get this error .

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\zoyoapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:719:10)
```

So the res.end is not ending the execution.Any way in which I could make it not show this error

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: your code seem to be incomplete without proper matching curly braces, can you post the complete code

Comment: @Sridhar hey I have done the edit

Comment: @sacDahal Do you want to skip the rest of the promise chain execution after `res.end(json);`?

Comment: @Sridhar yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` happens because you're sending response again at the end of the promise chain. You can break a promise chain early by rejecting it.

```
router.route('/getParkData/:parkLocationId').get(function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.parkLocationId;
    var parkdata = {};
    parkInfo(id).then(function(data) {
        if (data.parking_type == 'FREE') {
            return Promise.reject({
                type:'FREE_USER'
                data: JSON.stringify({
                "error": null,
                "result": null,
                "message": "free",
                "error_code": null
              })
            }); //rejecting this promise 
        } else {
            return getTwowheelers(id);
        }
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data[0].parking_type) {
            parkdata.parkingType = data[0].parking_type;
        } else {
            parkdata.parkingType = "paid";
        }

        if (data.length > 0) {
            parkdata.tw = data[0].rate.tw[0];
        } else {
            parkdata.tw = 0;
        }
        return getFourwheelers(id);
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            parkdata.fw = data[0].rate.fw[0];
        } else {
            parkdata.fw = 0;
        }
        res.json(mResponse.response(null, parkdata, "Success", 200));
    }).catch(function(err) {
        if(err.type === 'FREE_USER'){
            return res.send(err.data); // sending response only once
        }
        res.json(mResponse.response(null, null, "No data!", 500));
    });
```

Comment: wow thats a real nice way to do it, so we can reject a Promise anywhere but I didnot get how did you use the Promise without creating it I mean  return new Promise.reject({
                type:'FREE_USER'     this is how I know about Promise, a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, you can use static methods on `Promise` like `Promise.resolve()`, `Promise.reject()`. Here is [Mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Using_the_static_Promise.resolve_method) on that

Answer (score 0):

when the condition

```
if(data.parking_type == 'FREE')
```

is true it will response with json

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
  "error" : null,
  "result" : null,
  "message" : "free",
  "error_code" : null
});
res.end(json);
```

but the code will execute further in next then and next then at last it would find the command

```
res.json(mResponse.response(null, parkdata, "Success",200));
```

which try to set the header which causes error. i.e. you are try to send response after res.end();